# Inheritance involving subclass instances within superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have an object `A` which after instantiating, I do various operations to its state. Within the methods of `A`, I need to create multiple instances (call them `B`) of another class. The class of objects `B` rely heavily on much of the state of `A`, and the instances can influence `A`'s state.

The problem is as follows. Since `A` is already instantiated and operations are done on its state before the methods within `A` are invoked that require any instantiating of `B`, how can I use inheritance to write `B`'s class, given that I do not want to call `super()` within `B` (as `A` is already instantiated)?

Do I have to combine `B`'s class with `A`'s class here?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA instanceA = new ClassA(5000000L); //Initial instantiation and state-setting operation to A.
        instanceA.update(); //Try to get A to create B, where B relies on A's new state from previous operations.
    }   
}

class ClassA {
    long tempLong;
    ClassB instanceB;

    public ClassA(long setLong) {
        tempLong = setLong;
    }

    public void update() {
        this.instanceB = new ClassB(); //instanceA needs an instanceB to work with. 
    }

}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    long tempLong2;

    public ClassB() {
        // I don't want to call super() here because instanceA is already created and instanceA's state is already set!;
        this.tempLong2 = super.tempLong*2; //instaceA's state is necessary for instanceB to function!
    }
}
```

Comment: With code you can tell your problem with in 2 lines.

Comment: You have HAS-A and IS-A relation in one single stage? Does it really make sense of just as question this is being asked?

Comment: There's something off about your code design. Whenever I make a superclass dependent on one of its own subclasses in my code, I eventually find I need to refactor to get rid of the dependency. What are you trying to accomplish with this? (For instance, if each `ClassA` object needs a `ClassB` object internally, then each `ClassB` object needs one as well (since it is also a `ClassA`). Where does this stop?

Comment: @TedHopp All I want is a `ClassB` that can use all of `instanceA`'s state. I don't care about its ability to access `ClassA`'s methods. Does such functionality exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental flaw in your design. You seem to believe that when you call `update()`

```
public void update() {
    this.instanceB = new ClassB(); //instanceA needs an instanceB to work with. 
}
```

the new `ClassB` instance is related to `this` `ClassA` instance just because `ClassB extends ClassA`. NO, that isn't the case because `new ClassB()` creates an entirely new `Object` with a different `ClassA` state than `this`.

If the only property that `ClassB` depends on `ClassA` for is temprature you're better off passing it through the constructor and scrapping inheritance here (if `ClassB` IS-NOT-A `ClassA`).

```
public void update() {
    this.instanceB = new ClassB(this.tempLong);
}

public ClassB(long tempLong) {
    this.tempLong2 = tempLong * 2;
}
```

If the dependency requires access to almost all of `ClassA` properties, it may make more sense to favour HAS-A over inheritance here by passing `ClassA` instance to `ClassB`.

```
public void update() {
    this.instanceB = new ClassB(this); // ClassA passes itself
}

public ClassB(ClassA classA) {
    this.classA = classA; // ClassB HAS-A ClassA relationship
    this.tempLong2 = classA.getTempLong() * 2;
}
```

Comment: In my real life problem `instanceA`'s state is huge, which is why I'm trying not to pass through a constructor (since constructor would be 5 lines long!)

Comment: Prefer HAS-A in that case. You'd have access to all of its state.

Comment: Rightly said by @Ravi, you should "Favor composition over inheritance", a very nice information can be found in Item 16 for Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, where he explained why to Favor composition.